Prove That There Exists Maximally One Cycle In The Annulus, When $\nabla \cdot F <0$.
Assume that $\dot{x} = F(x)$ is a differential equation defined in an annulus $A = \{1 <
(x^2 + y^2) < 4 \}$ and assume that $A$ is left invariant under the differential equation.
Assume that $div(F)(x, y) < 0$ everywhere in the annulus. Prove that there can exist
maximally one cycle in $A$.
I don't know how to use Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, and is there a solution without using that theorem, I mean only basic theorems like Green's theorem or something else.
Thank you for your time.

I think you can directly apply the Green's/divergence Theorem...suppose that  there is a periodic solution, supported on a $\mathcal{C}^1$ curve, say $\gamma$, contained in the open annulus. By the Green's theorem the intergal of the divergence over the region "encercled'' by $\gamma$ must be $0$. Now suppose that there is another closed orbit...by uniqueness of solutions, its support is disjoint to $\gamma$...so it is "either outside or inside"...can the integral of the divergence be $0$ also on this other region?
